# All the dominoes laid out in a chain (the number of spots on the ends of adjacent dominies match ).If oneend of the chain is$5$, what is the other end

Tags: combinatorics

All the dominoes are laid out in a chain (such that the number of spots on the ends of adjacent dominies match ).If one end of the chain is $5$, what is at the other end?
The introduction before this question , as written in the book:
*"Problems 10 and 11 concern a set of dominoes consisting 2×1 rectangles with 0 to 6 spots on each square . All 28 possible pairs of number of spots (including doubles) are represented.  The game is played by forming a chain in which squares of adjacent dominoes have equal numbers of spots"*

Well, the question I mentioned at the top is problem 10. I dont have an idea what the problem is implying ...neither the thing given as introduction before the problem(which I have attached above) make any sense to me...I qm not getting the idea behind it...

Comment: How many fives occur in such a standard domino set?

Comment: Are you familiar with actual dominoes and what they look like? https://www.stem.org.uk/news-and-views/opinions/10-ways-use-dominoes-your-mathematics-classroom

Comment: @Slip eternal I want to know what does question trying to imply...

Comment: @paw88789 yes.. i mean dominoes are just wooden strips of varied areas typically a square shsped or a rectangle shaped...but what does they mean by "doubles" or " spots"?

Comment: @Slip Also what does they mean by $28$  possible pairs.. i mean what pair?

Comment: @Franklin See link in my previous comment to see what dominoes look like. On each half of a domino there will be some number of spots (between 0 and 6 inclusive). so for instance a 5-3 domino will have 5 spots on one half of the tile and 3 on the other. There are not separate 3-5 and 5-3 dominoes. Doubles means the same number of spots on each side (such as 4-4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can consider dominoes as integer number pairs where both numbers are from 0 to 6. For example (1,0) is domino one side of which has one spot and other has no spot. (1,0) and (0,1) is the same domino. Domino where two sides have the same number of spots is double, for example (5,5). There is exactly 7 doubles (0,0), (1,1), ...(6,6).

In full domino set there are exactly 8 exemplars of each number: 6 on non-doubles and 2 on a double. For example number 3 is on dominoes (3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6) and twice at (3,3).

Correct domino placement is such that neighbor domino are touching with matching number. Like (1,3)(3,5)(5,6)(6,0)... Then for correct domino placement all inner numbers are happening in pairs.

Suppose that other end of domino placement is not number 5. Then there must be 7 exemplars of number 5 in inner numbers which contradicts previous paragraph. So other end of domino placement should be number 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how do we prove if one side of a domino is $5$ then the other side domino number must be $5$ ..but i mean how did u get to that conclusion ..can you please explain it ?

Comment: There is even count of each number in inner numbers of chain (touching numbers are matching), and there is even count of each number in total (8 exemplars), that's why there must be even count of each number on ends.

Comment: It's true that that there is an even count of numbers in inner chain and even count of each number in $8$ examplars ..but if the last no. of the chain is $5$ then we are talking about the other end ...if it is not $5$ ...what will be contradictory?

Comment: Then total count of number 5 will be not even as it must be because 8 is even.